# gcc generates 32bit code on sparc

Tags: gcc, solaris, 32bit-64bit

I have a Solaris sparc machine and when i build my programs, it generates 32bit code which should be 64bit. How to check the cause?

$uname -a
SunOS sol 5.10 Generic_118833-33 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240
$/usr/sfw/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$/usr/sfw/bin/gcc test.c
$file a.out
a.out:          ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not    stripped, no debugging information available
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OSNews - SPARC Optimizations With GCC](http://www.osnews.com/story/6136)

> The creation of 64-bit code requires using the `-m64` flag (`-m32` for 32-bit code is implied by default).

(Yes, this is different than GCC for x86_64, which defaults to `-m64` unless overridden with `-m32`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to force a 64-bit build using the `-m64` option.

If that fails, you can download and install a prebuilt GCC package with 64-bit SPARC support for Solaris 10 from [SunFreeware.com](http://sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#gcc34) (download, `gunzip`, install with `pkgadd -d gcc-...-sparc-local`) which will run from `/usr/local/bin/gcc`.

Comment: Yes it turn out to be 32bit. But why? Is it selected during package installation?

Comment: @Adil Unlike on x86_64, 64-bit SPARC code requires more memory for no performance gain over 32-bit, so it is best only used when the 32-bit address space is insufficient.  SPARC userspace is therefore 32-bit by default, even when the hardware and kernel are 64-bit.